# Set rotation_euler beyond 360° with python

Tags: python

I animate a camera using an empty. In order to show some objects I need to rotate the emtpy (and though the camera) beyond 360°.

I can set any values manually, but setting

```
obj.rotation_euler.x = -4.9217
```

Sets it actual value to 76.7° causing camera to make a full 360° turn.

My question: how can I assign any values using python, like I can enter they manually.

**UPDATE**: As @batFINGER pointed out, the convertion from -4.9217 to 76.7° is not happening immediately, but after further transformation. In my case I have:

```
obj.rotation_euler.x = -4.9217
obj.rotation_euler.rotate_axis("Z", 0.01)
```

So my question can be rewritten as:

**How can I rotate around local axis without loosing rotation values over 360°?**

Comment: Please elaborate. Setting default cube rotation as above in python console results in expected -282 degrees.  However if I flip to quaternion rotation and back will get 78 degrees via the conversion.

Comment: @batFINGER You are right! Didn't noticed it. I updated the question.